# Does Node.js Stream count towards your webhost traffic bandwidth allocation?

Tags: node.js, proxy, stream, streaming, hosting

I'm building a client-side JS app, and trying to save money on hosting costs.

This might be a dump question, but when you use Node.js Stream to pipe 3rd party resources, for proxying an image/video for example, does that count towards your webhost's traffic/bandwidth allocation?

For example code like the following:

```
...
  var request = require('request');
...
app.get('/myimage',function(req,res){
  request('http://3rdparty.com/bigImage.png').pipe(res); 
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: It probably does, but now the server is downloading, not uploading like it would normally do when a user is downloading.

Comment: It's going to count.  Your bring it into your server from the outside world and then you're sending it out in the request.  So, it's going both ways through your bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- it would most definitely count as you're moving data across your providers network over the public internet.